# Function pointer usage with hierarchical control: xtern/namespace C++

Tags: c, c++11, pointers, function-pointers, extern

> Below is a sample usage from an older and newer version of a software stack. How would the function usage and access differ with the hierarchical structuring of the two pieces of
>   code below:

```
namespace std
{
    typedef void (*function)();
    extern "C" function fn_ptr(function) throw();
}
```

And

```
extern "C++" 
{
  namespace std
  {
      typedef void (*function)();
      function fn_ptr(function) throw();
  }
}
```

> The first one is easy but I wish to access fn_ptr from both C and
>   C++ based files in the 2nd example. Note that it is extern "C++" and there isn't much to find about extern "C++" usage on Stackoverflow or Google.

Comment: You should throw away that software stack. Adding to the `std` namespace leads to *undefined behavior* (with a very few exceptions, and the shown is not one of them).

Comment: Also note that adding `extern "C"` isn't some magic thing that will turn C++ constructs (like namespaces or `throw` specifiers) into working C code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the unique approach to accessing a function defined in C++ from C. extern "C++" is implicit by default in standard.

Let us assume that you have a .c file (FileC.c) and you wish to call a function defined in .cpp (FileC++.cpp). Let us define the function in C++ file as:

```
void func_in_cpp(void) 
{ 
  // whatever you wanna do here doesn't matter what I am gonna say!
}
```

> Do the following steps now (to be able to call the above function from
>   a .c file):

1) With you regular C++ compiler (or [www.cpp.sh](http://www.cpp.sh)), write a very simple program that includes your function name (func_in_cpp). Compile your program. E.g.

```
$ g++ FileC++.cpp -o test.o
```

2) Find the mangled name of your function.

```
$ nm test.out | grep -i func_in_cpp
[ The result should be "_Z11func_in_cppv" ]
```

3) Go to your C program and do two things:

```
void _Z11func_in_cppv(void);  // provide the external function definition at the top in your program. Function is extern by default in C.

int main(void) 
{
    _Z11func_in_cppv();   // call your function to access the function defined in .cpp file
}
```

Comment: Here's a much simpler solution. Define this function and compile it with C++: `extern "C" void call_func_in_cpp() { func_in_cpp(); }`. Then declare and call that function from your C code. (Declare it as `void call_func_in_cpp(void);`)

Answer (score 1):

The second version does not allow direct access from a program written in C.

Of course, nothing stops the C program from calling some other C++ function declared `extern "C"`, which in turn calls `std::fn_ptr`.

---

Although this point has been hammered into the ground in comments, it's worth noting that you are not allowed to define your own names in namespace `std`. Presumably the code you are quoting comes from a library implementation designed to be used in a stand-alone environment. Using namespace `std` is not relevant to the issue, and is just a distraction from your question.

Comment: @Sammy: from C++, you just access it normally as `std::fn_ptr`. Any problem you are experiencing using the function probably derives from not linking in the library in which it is actually defined.

Comment: Sure, I get that. Thanks.